# Override tunnel-all VPN connection to print locally

Tags: vpn, tunnel, sonicwall

We have a remote office with several users. The users connect to the cable modem there and individually VPN to our NSA2650 via Sonicwall Global VPN client. This client is set to tunnel-all mode because of cookie and session stuff. Unfortunately, when the VPN is connected, the local printer at the remote office is not accessible because all of the traffic is being tunneled. The VPN client takes over the network interface and not even pinging the printer works. I got on with support and they said it was impossible. It looks like other manufacturers have split-tunnel or similar functionality, but Sonicwall support confirmed there was no way to do something similar with their firewall.

Is there a way to create a static or other route on the machines that would allow traffic to reach the printer while the VPN is connected? NB: the VPN and LANs are on different subnets.

Comment: "_Is there a way to create a static or other route on the machines that would allow traffic to reach the printer while the VPN is connected?_" That is split tunneling, and if the VPN does not support it, then you cannot access any local devices.

Comment: So the route configuration on the machine has no bearing nor any way to override what the VPN client is doing?

Comment: The VPN client gets its orders from the firewall, and it will look for routing table changes on the host and remove them while it is running.

Comment: And it's safe to assume that those instructions are updated regularly while the client is running so that any changes made to the routing table after the client is started are going to be overwritten by the client soon after they are made? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. You can make and use routing table changes while not connected to the VPN, but the VPN client software monitors and reverses any changes while it is running, Split tunneling is a security risk because it opens a hole in the firewall for the business that can be exploited on purpose of by accident.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that somehow and for some reason, enabling ipv6 (it was disabled before) allows the printer to be discovered, added and printed to while the VPN is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Sonicwall is 100% wrong. Their own documentation shows easy instructions to enable split tunnel.

NETWORK | SSL VPN | Client Settings screen, configure Default Device Profile.
https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-allow-sslvpn-users-access-to-the-internet-when-using-tunnel-all-mode/170505877560278/

https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-configure-ipsec-client-based-vpn-for-remote-users/170505850768290/

Comment: Thanks, but that is using the SSL VPN config/client which isn't the same as the Global VPN client. The global VPN client uses either wireguard or ipsec and neither link has relevant info. The first link seems to just describe how to allow access to the internet which is not my issue, we can already access the internet and it is tunneled as we want. The second link just describes how to set up the Global VPN connection, it doesn't say anything about printing locally with tunnel all mode on.

Comment: Edit: I see now in the second link, the section on client connections, in the dropdown, set "allow connections to" and set "split tunnels". I will try once people disconnect for the day. Thanks and sorry for not reading more carefully earlier. I still am not clear on how the first link fits in, I don't see Network > SSLVPN config, and in the SSLVPN > Client settings config, I don't see anything about split tunnels...the link seems to just describe how to turn on tunnel all mode and add WAN remote access networks to allow internet which I already have.